# How to use Mockito/stubbing to mock a String.length to a particular value

Tags: java, string, mockito, stubbing

I need to simulate a scenario where my test needs to be returning a particular value for String.length function
i.e-
String str[]= abc.getValue();

if(String.length != 100){//do this} else {//do that}

I want to mock String length to return 100 so that I can execute else loop

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't mock (default)methods like `String.length()` - write your test properly: provide a String with a value of the length you want to test. A test should test whether the method returns the defined output for a defined input - nothing else.

Comment: Which version of Mockito are you using? Did you try it and what were your results then?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java 11 or above, you can use this to create a String of length 100 and avoid the mocking:

```
String s = "x".repeat(100)
```